# Count specific array values starts something

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array:

```
$array = array("pg_1","pg_2","pg_3","pg_4","pg_5","qr_1","qr_2","qr_3");
```

**I want to count the  values which is  starts with pg.**

So far i have tried below code :

```
$arraycount = array_count_values($array);

$countpg = $arraycount['pg%'];
```

I forgot that I have keys and values:

```
$array = Array ( [pg_1] => 2 [pg_2] => 3 [pg_3] => 2 [pg_4] => 4 [pg_5] => 1 [gp_1] => 1 [gp_2] => 4 [gp_3] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If value contains `pg`, then increment `$i`

```
$array = array("pg_1","pg_2","pg_3","pg_4","pg_5","qr_1","qr_2","qr_3");
$i = 0;

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, 'pg') !== false) { 
       $i++;
    }
}
echo $i;
```

Just noticed your edit...

For an Associative Array, just change the `Foreach` loop to look at `$key` and `$value` and query the `$key` rather than `$value` as shown the last example.

```
$array = ["pg_1" => 2, "pg_2" => 3, "pg_3" => 2, "pg_4" => 4, "pg_5" => 1, "gp_1" => 1, "gp_2" => 4, "gp_3" => 3];
$i = 0;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'pg') !== false) { 
       $i++;
    }
}
echo $i;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array("pg_1","pg_2","pg_3","pg_4","pg_5","qr_1","qr_2","qr_3");

$count = count(array_filter($array, function($item) {
    return strpos($item, 'pg') === 0;
}));

echo $count;
```

You are filtering the items that starts with 'pg' and then count the results.

Answer (score 2):

> Use Below Method:-

$array = array("pg_1","pg_2","pg_3","pg_4","pg_5","qr_1","qr_2","qr_3");

```
$search_val = preg_quote('pg', '*');

$result = preg_grep('*' . $search_val . '*', $array);

count($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

One line solution is use **[preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)** function

Try below code :

```
$array = array("pg_1","pg_2","pg_3","pg_4","pg_5","qr_1","qr_2","qr_3");
$count = count(preg_grep('/pg/',$array));
echo $count;
```

For more reference of function refer this link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Answer (score 0):

I would use array filter here:

```
$array = array("pg_1","pg_2","pg_3","pg_4","pg_5","qr_1","qr_2","qr_3");

$c = count(array_filter($array, "getPG"));

function getPG($key)
{
    return strpos($key, "pg_") === 0;
}

echo 'count: ' .$c;
```

You will have a correct count of array elements that begin with "pg_" stored in `$c`.